# My Schengen visa is in my old passport with my maiden name and new passport has married name

Tags: visas, schengen, france

My Schengen visa is in my old passport with my maiden name and new passport has married name. Can I travel to France? As far as I know it’s okay with both passports and marriage certificate but I would like confirmation.